# Constrained types from a type provider (XmlProvider)

Tags: f#, f#-data

I derive great value from XmlProvider as it gives me a ton of type definitions when I load an XML or XSD. However, consider this XML:

```
<period>
    <start>01/01/2018</start>
    <end>02/02/2018</end>
</period>
```

Can I sweet talk the type provider into giving me a constrained data type such that "end" may not precede "start". Or maybe bolt on some constraints after XmlProvider does the heavy lifting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would treat this as an edge-case, and consider it an "unvalidated model". As such, typically in F#, we would use a validation function to turn that unvalidated model into a validated model. (I usually use `Result<'T, 'E>` for that.)

```
let validateXmlDates xml =
    if xml.period.start > xml.period.end then
        Error "Period start must be before period end"
    else Ok xml
```

Now, anything you do should expect a `Result<XmlType, string>`, which will allow you to pass it around with a guarantee that it matches your requirements. You may also use `Result.bind` to chain validations<sup>1</sup>:

```
Ok xml
|> Result.bind (validateXmlDates)
|> Result.bind (validateXml...)
|> Result.bind (validateXml...)
```

Somewhat related reading: [Railway Oriented Programming (F# for Fun and Profit)](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/)

Once you have the results, a trivial `match` can be used to trigger the next step:

```
match validatedXml with
| Ok xml -> ...
| Error str -> ...
```

You would then do the next logical step in the `Ok` branch, and handle errors in the `Error` branch.

1: `Result.bind (fn)` is effectively a short-hand for the following:

```
match result with
| Error e -> Error e
| Ok v -> fn v
```